# Unable to connect to Kafka(in docker) from Internet

Tags: apache-kafka

I am attempting to make it so I can connect to Kafka from over the internet. I have opened Ports: 9092 and 2181 on my router.

I have had no luck at all! I am using OffsetExplorer and I am able to ping kafka from another network. The IP of the system that is is running on is: 10.0.1.104

I AM able to connect to kafka on the local network from another computer though.

Here is my Kafka Docker-Compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    environment:
      JVMFLAGS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper_jaas.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./zookeeper_jaas.conf:/etc/zookeeper/zookeeper_jaas.conf
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.13-2.8.1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 29092:29092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:9093,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9093,EXTERNAL://10.0.1.104:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: 'yes'
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      KAFKA_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS: PLAIN
      KAFKA_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL: PLAIN
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_jaas.conf"
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_server_jaas.conf:/etc/kafka/kafka_jaas.conf
```

Connection attempts result in this on Kafka's output
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show your logs as text, and your client logs running over the internet, not Zookeeper server. Your client will probably timeout over the internet due to latency alone. I suggest you use REST proxy and add authentication before opening Kafka to the open internet. Also try kcat rather than ping

Comment: And definitely don't expose Zookeeper to the internet. You can use other tools than offset explorer to browse data, even hosted in Docker with their own web server forwarded through your router... Or, you could pay for Kafka hosted service and not worry about any networking/security